# Custom configuration files - Play! Framework 2.0

Tags: java, file, playframework-2.0, custom-configuration

I have a question about loading properties from custom configuration files. I have tried
two different approaches to loading my `oauth.properties` file but I can't
get either to work so I'm hoping someone here can help me.

The first approach I tried was to add the file to the conf directory
and reference it thusly:

```
String oauthPropertiesFile = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("oauth.properties").getFile();
```

But that just returned `NULL`.

The second approach I tries was to add:

```
@include.oauthProperties = oauth.properties
```

to the `application.conf` file and then reference it in
my controller like:

```
String clientId = oauthProperties.clientId;
```

However this doesn't compile.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if conf is part of the classpath. So I would try `/conf/oauth.properties` or put the file into the classpath. Furthermore you should use `Play.application.classloader()` instead of Classloader.

About the include: I still think you need to call `Play.application().configuration().get("clientID");`

To analyze the situation you can start the app with `-Dconfig.trace=loads` and analyse the configuration with `Play.application().configuration().root().render()`.

Hope this give you enough hints so that you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 16):

What worked for me with a file in `/conf`:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

val myConfig = ConfigFactory.load("myfile.properties").getConfig("my.config.prefix")
```

Answer (score 6):

In a generic case, to fetch any File from the "/conf" directory, using Play 2.2 it can be done as follows (note that "/conf" is on the classpath, so you should not include it).

```
Play.application().classloader().getResource("any_file");
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use `scala.io.Source` you can also do something like

```
Source.fromFile(Play.getFile("path-in-your-play-project"))
```