# Play framework, i18n "messages.*" in subfolders

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I want to put `conf/messages` into subfolder, like `conf/lang/messages`. There is nothing about this in documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaI18N.

Did someone resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Messages.scala source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/702e89841fc54f5603a0d981c3488ed9883561fe/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala) has a clue:

```
protected val messagesPrefix =
  config.getDeprecated[Option[String]]("play.i18n.path", "messages.path")
```

I have not tried it in 2.4 yet, but it looks worth taking for a spin.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the sub-directory in `application.conf` by adding:

```
play.i18n.path = "lang"
```

Doing so will tell Play to read the messages files from `conf/lang`.